# Laravel attribute $hidden on model not working(still showing the hidden one even I already specificed in the $hidden array )

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'activated',
        'token',
    ];
}
```

Above is the list of attribute that I want it hidden from display , but when I using

```
 $users = User::leftJoin('countries','users.nationality_id','=','countries.id')
            ->selectRaw("
                users.*,
                countries.name as nationality_name
            ")
            ->where('users.id','=',$user_id)
            ->get();
```

and after this when I `dd($user);`,it still showing the hidden attributes

[image]
and as you can see based on the screenshot image above ,  'password',
        'remember_token',
        'activated',
        'token', are still showing.

Any Idea ?

Comment: don't dump, just return the `$users` and see if its still showing?

Comment: check `original` instead `attribute`

Comment: can you try the same code without leftJoin for a while to confirm that the hidden is actually working or not?
and check with print_r()

Comment: You are having a contradiction over here you are hidding them in the model and showing them in selectRaw

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Manual says:

> Hiding Attributes From Array Or JSON Conversion
>
> Sometimes you may wish to limit the attributes that are included in
>   your model's array or JSON form, such as passwords. To do so, add a
>   hidden property definition to your model.

So, If you try

```
get()->toArray();
```

they will be hidden.

Test:

```
dd(User::find(1)->toArray());
dd(User::find(1));
```

Comment: You don't need to use `toArray()` to hide attributes from the JSON response. You can simply write `return User::find(1);` and it will hide those attributes from the JSON response. But if you use `dd()`, it won't work.